# windows.location not working on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a bit of an issue with a click event not firing properly. The click event I am refering to is the one at the bottom of the page attached to #sales. I used microsoft.com just to be sure that it wasn't the page I was trying to navigate to.Any help would be appreciated and the code is bellow.

```
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function() {

$(".intro-no-js").css("visibility","hidden");
$(".intro-javascript").css("visibility","visible");

//defines how max should be animated
jQuery.fn.maxanimate = function () { 
this.css("position","absolute"); 

    var t = (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop(); 

    var l = (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft(); 

    $(this).animate({
        top: t,
        left: l-79.5
    }, 500);

    return this; 
} 


//defines how xim should be animated
jQuery.fn.ximanimate = function () { 
this.css("position","absolute"); 

    var t = (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop(); 

    var r = (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft(); 

    $(this).animate({
        top: t,
        left: r+78.5
    }, 500);

    return this; 
} 

//defines how top arrows should be animated
jQuery.fn.arrowsanimate = function () { 
this.css("position","absolute"); 

    var t = (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop(); 
    var l = (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft(); 

    $(this).animate({
        top: t-25,
        left: l
    }, 500);

    return this; 
} 

//defines how bottom section should be animated
jQuery.fn.animatebottom = function () { 
this.css("position","absolute"); 

    var b = (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop(); 
    var l = (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft(); 

    $(this).animate({
        bottom: b-22,
        left: l
    }, 500);

    return this; 
}

//max starting co-ordinates
var maxl = $(window).width() - 157; 
var maxt =  ($(window).height() - $("#intro-max").outerHeight()) / 2; 

//xim starting co-ordinates
var ximr = $(window).width() - 159; 
var ximt = ($(window).height() - $("#intro-xim").outerHeight()) / 2; 

//arrows starting co-ordinates
var al = (($(window).width() -  $("#intro-xim").outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft()+ 35; 
var at = 0; 

//bottom of logo starting co-ordinates
var bl = (($(window).width() -  $("#intro-xim").outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft()-50;
var bt = 0;

//set initial co-ordinates for all divs
$("#intro-arrows").css({position: "absolute",top: at,left: al});    
$("#intro-max").css({position: "absolute",top: maxt,right: maxl});
$("#intro-xim").css({position: "absolute",top: ximt,left: ximr});
$(".intro-bottom").css({position: "absolute", bottom: bt, left: bl});

//lets bring it all to life!
$("#intro-max").maxanimate();
$("#intro-xim").ximanimate();
$("#intro-arrows").arrowsanimate();
$(".intro-bottom").animatebottom();



$("#sales").click(function() {
    window.location = "http://www.microsoft.com"; 
});

});
```

My Markup is as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Maxxim - Welcome</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/intro.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/intro.css">
<body>
<div class="intro-no-js">
<img src="imgs/intro/Intro-logo.gif" alt="Maxxim Logo">
<a href="sales-and-marketing.html" title="Sales & Marketing"><img src="imgs/intro/Intro-sales-butt.gif" alt="Sales & Marketing" id="sales"></a>
<a href="design.html" title="Design"><img src="imgs/intro/Intro-design-butt.gif" alt="Design" id="design"></a>
</div>

<div class="intro-javascript">
<div id="intro-arrows"></div>
<div id="intro-max"></div>
<div id="intro-xim"></div>

<div class="intro-bottom">
    <div id="pants"></div>
    <div id="sales"></div>
    <div id="design"></div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body
{
background-color: #000;
margin: 0 0;
}

/* Styling for if javascript is disabled */
.intro-no-js
{
width: 317px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative; 
top: 275px;
}

.intro-no-js sales
{
float: left;
}

.intro-no-js design
{
float: left;
}

.intro-no-js img
{
border: none;
}

/* Styling for animation if javascript is enabled */
.intro-javascript
{
visibility: visible;
}

#intro-arrows
{
background-image:url(../imgs/intro/Intro-logo_top.png);
width: 53px;
height: 13px;
}

#intro-max
{
background-image:url(../imgs/intro/Intro-logo_left.png);
width: 159px;
height: 72px;
}

#intro-xim
{
background-image:url(../imgs/intro/Intro-logo_right.png);
width: 157px;
height: 72px;
}


.intro-bottom
{
width: 317px;
}
#pants
{
margin: 0 auto;
background-image: url(../imgs/intro/Intro-logo_bottom.png);
width: 80px;
height: 37px;

}

#sales
{
background-image: url(../imgs/intro/Intro-sales-butt.gif);
width: 218px;
height: 8px;
float: left;
}

#sales:hover
{
background-image: url(../imgs/intro/Intro-sales-butt-o.gif);
}

#design
{
background-image:url(../imgs/intro/Intro-design-butt.gif);
width: 99px;
height: 8px;
float: left;
}

#design:hover
{
background-image:url(../imgs/intro/Intro-design-butt-o.gif);
}
```

Comment: Does the onclick function trigger. Also see http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring regarding sensible use of the $.fn namespace.

Comment: Can you show us some HTML code at all? This could be happening for a number of reasons...what happens when you just put an `alert("foo");` in the click function?

Comment: What's the URL of the page this is on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this.

```
$("#sales").click(function() {
    window.location.href = "http://www.microsoft.com"; 
    return false;//Just in case if it is a link prevent default behavior
});
```

Looking at the link you provided I found the issue. You have same ids to multiple element on the page. So when you try to fetch element by id and if there are multiple elements on the page jQuery returns the first element with that id.

You have `<img src="imgs/intro/Intro-sales-butt.gif" alt="Sales & Marketing" id="sales">` as well on the page which has the same id `sales`. Change the id it should work fine.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve the issue. I do appreciate your help though.

Comment: Do you see any error on the page load? Is the event getting attached?

Comment: im not seeing any errors pop up on page load, you can view the page at http://www.cspsolutions.ca/Maxxim